# Position like ConstraintLayout in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, position

I'm currently new in mobile development and Now I'm studying about flutter, for now I'm confused about location of widget in flutter. is there any command like constraintlayout in flutter or something more efficient?

i have a code like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FailedScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FailedScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF39B54A),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 20.0),
              child: const Text(
                "Detail Transaksi",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 50, // Set to null to align to the bottom
            bottom: null, // Adjust the value as needed
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset('images/ic_failed.png'),
                  Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0) ),
                  const Text(
                    "Transaksi Gagal",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 130,
            bottom: null,
            left: 400,
            right: 400,
            child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color:Colors.white ,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text("Kirim Dana"),
                const Text("Pihak tujuan tidak merespon, saldo syariah gagal terpotong")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see,there is like Positioned() to adjust the widget position and I'm feel that it is not efficient and time consuming because I always need to see the result, can you guys provide me an information or how to adjust position with like constraintlayout in flutter?

thank you guys

Comment: I think the most conventional way to make layouts is to use a combination of `Row` and `Column` widgets to make a layout. The `Positioned` inside a `Stack` like you used is also not uncommon, but I think in most cases rows and columns are better. I don't think there really is an equivalent of a `ConstraintLayout` in Flutter